# low level file input output calculate "sum" and "average"

Tags: c

this is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 512
int main()
{
        int infd;
        int bytes;
        int i;
        int outfd;
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

        if((infd = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY)) <0)
        {
                perror("Can't open file d11-9.in");
        }
        if((outfd = open("output.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, S_IWRITE))<0)
        {
                printf("Can\t open file output.txt");
        }

        while((bytes = read (infd, buffer, BUFFERSIZE))>0)
        {
                for(i=0;i<bytes; ++i)
                {
                        putchar(buffer[i]);
                }
                write(outfd, buffer, bytes);
        }
        close(infd); 
        close(outfd);
        return 0;
}
```

this is input.txt

```
ID              UNIX    C Language      Network
20150001        98      95              97
20150002        84      88              90
```

this is output.txt

```
ID              UNIX    C Language      Networ  sum     average
20150001        98      95              97      290     96
20150002        84      88              90      262     84
```

I want to code read input.txt and calculate sum and average!!
make like output.txt

I don't know how to code
pls give me a hand!!

Comment: You should read it line by line, parse out numbers, compute sum and avg, then write out entire result as a line.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html

Comment: Functions `read()` and `write()` and their cousins are used for binary files. Reading a text file would be better using `fgets()` and analysing the contents of each line, then outputting that line with the extra fields you calculate. Bear in mind that `fgets()` retains any `newline`, which you'll have to remove if you want to append text to that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions `read()` and `write()` and their cousins are used for binary files. Reading a text file would be better using `fgets()` and analysing the contents of each line, then outputting that line with the extra fields you calculate. Bear in mind that `fgets()` retains any `newline`, which has to be removed before appending text to that line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LLEN 100

int main(void)
{
    FILE *inf, *outf;
    int val1, val2, val3, sum;
    char buff[LLEN];

    if((inf = fopen("input.txt", "rt")) == NULL) {
        perror("Can't open file input.txt");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((outf = fopen("output.txt", "wt")) == NULL) {
        perror("Can\t open file output.txt");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(fgets(buff, LLEN, inf) == NULL) {            // read the header
        perror("Cannot read header line");
        exit(1);
    }
    buff [ strcspn(buff, "\r\n") ] = '\0';          // truncate any newline
    fprintf(outf, "%s sum     average\n", buff);    // write expanded header line

    while(fgets(buff, LLEN, inf) != NULL) {         // read each line
        buff [ strcspn(buff, "\r\n") ] = '\0';      // truncate any newline
        if(sscanf(buff, "%*s%d%d%d", &val1, &val2, &val3) != 3) {   // ignore ID
            perror("Cannot convert fields");
            exit(1);
        }
        sum = val1 + val2 + val3;
        fprintf(outf, "%s%9d%7d \n", buff, sum, sum/3);
    }

    if (fclose(outf))
        perror("Unable to close output file");
    fclose(inf); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output file:

```
ID              UNIX    C Language      Network sum     average
20150001        98      95              97      290     96 
20150002        84      88              90      262     87
```

Incidentally your average was incorrect on the last line!

Comment: thank you for answer!!
can I ask one more thing?
how to conver this code to low-level??
thanks

Comment: Oooh! Funnily enough [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186884/how-to-convert-high-level-to-low-level-in-c-language) has ripped off this answer and wants to go low level too. Please give me some credit for my effort.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I'm not good at Eng.
sorry for everything.

Comment: Thank you for the vote, even thought the answer is not "low level", at least you have working code to go on from.